# php-fed Highcharts time series throws T_variable error, why?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, highcharts

I am VERY green when it comes to php and I have been playing around with highcharts to learn charting software. I'm trying to run [this](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series) chart demo from a database, but the code for variable time is throwing me for a loop. can anyone help?

This is the example code block from highcharts regarding scraping the datetime and values from a db:

here is my code:

```
<?php
    include ("connect.php");
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT click, datetime FROM mytable");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        extract $row;
        $datetime *= 1000; // convert from Unix timestamp to JavaScript time
        $data[] = "[$datetime, $clicks]";

}
?>
```

The error is thrown on the extract call,line five in this case. the error is `"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE"`. Is this line pseudocode or something? is there no compatability with mysqli? What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Communicate your php layer with javascript by json_encode(), in this case we have no see how you communicate php and javascirpt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

`extract $row;`

to

```
extract ($row);
```

[extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) is a PHP function and not a language construct like `include` or `require`.

So, you can't call it without parenthesis.